# How can I change a column value in MSSQL 2008 to NEGATIVE based on the condition of another field?

Tags: sql-server-2008

One of the columns in my dataset **(Col3)** contains positive values for all records.  I need some of these values to be negative based on the text value of another field.
For example:

> C1   C2    C3
>   1    **C**    20
>   2    D    50
>   3    D    37
>   4    D    20
>   5    **C**    50

I need to change every value in Col3 to negative value when Col2 contains a 'C'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
set col3 = -col3
where charindex('C', col2) > 0
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this dynamically because the dataset is not a static table.  The result needs to be passed to an SSRS report.

Comment: No idea what you mean. But you can use dynamic SQL. Look up `EXEC()`